# Should I use and loop, or just a loop?

Tags: c#, performance, .net, linq

I have this code:

```
if(listObj.Any(x => x.id < 0))
{
    foreach(ModelClass item in listObj)
    {
        if(item.id < 0)
        {
            // code to create a new Obj in the database
        }
    }
}
```

But, should I use like this?

```
foreach(ModelClass item in listObj)
{
    if(item.id < 0)
    {
        // code to create a new Obj in the database
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** It's unusual to exist `id < 0` (I use this to create a temp `id` for manipulation in the page), but there is a possibility.

---

Extra info that I found:

- [Query transformations are syntactic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/query-transformations-are-syntactic)
- [IMPROVE YOUR LINQ WITH .ANY()](http://www.headspring.com/improve-your-linq-with-any/)
- [MSDN Documentation - Enumerable.Any Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

Comment: us a simple for loop and not a foreach and remove any linq code if you need performance
and if you need to do it really fast use an unmanaged for loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.Where` extension method to filter the records you need:

```
foreach(ModelClass item in listObj.Where(x => x.id < 0))
{
    // code to create a new Obj in the database
}
```

Comment: Related: [LINQ extension methods - Any() vs. Where() vs. Exists()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703256/linq-extension-methods-any-vs-where-vs-exists)

Comment: that would kill performance as you effectively create a 2nd loop plus an object that needs to be allocated and managed by the GC

Comment: @WalterVehoeven There are no inner loops, the collection is scanned once. There is a certain performance penalty for executing a delegate and having an iterator but in most real-world cases its effect is negligible.

Comment: well you have 2 loops, one in your where linq statement and one in the foreach.LINQ is no "free ride"

Comment: Let's measure it in O notation. The statement is O(N), where N is the number of elements in the `listObj`. Same as in the original statement. For most scenarios that's what matters.